# iDangero.us Swiper Slider resetting to initial slide on scroll up on Safari Mobile

Tags: ios, safari, swiper.js

Can't find anything in the docs about how to solve this issue, doesn't seem to happen on any other browser.

The index of the initial slide is 4 and when I scroll up on mobile, instead of maintaining the index of the slide I swiped to it returns to 4.

Anybody else dealt with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

window resized when you scolled up on safari,
and swiper updated when windows updated,
set `updateOnWindowResize:false` to fix it if your swiper version is `> v5.2.1` .